# Ubuntu 16.04 - no sound in headphone after sleep - how to troubleshoot

Tags: sound, suspend, headphones

On boot-up; my headphones work reliably.

Intermittently; after a sleep; the headphones will show up in the 'play sound through' list in `All Settings - Sound` - but when selected, no sound is played through the head phones.

If I select the *Built-in Audio* option; I do get sound out of my laptop speakers.

Any recommendations on how to trouble shoot this further would be most appreciated.

Comment: You can find the answer here - https://superuser.com/questions/1047666/headphone-jack-stops-working-after-suspend-reboot